# CSS Margin and padding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing a difficulty to make the drop down list looks good as it has messed up with CSS

**DEMO.HTML**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
<style>
li{
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='wrap'>
        <div id="clickable_div">MENU</div>
            <div id="nav_menu">
                <ul class="dropDown">
                    <li id="li_1"><img src="images/ori_12.png"></li>
                    <li id="li_2"><img src="images/ori_14.png"></li>
                    <li id="li_3"><img src="images/ori_15.png"></li>
                    <li id="li_4"><img src="images/ori_16.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script>

        $('#wrap').mouseover( function(){
            $('#nav_menu').slideDown();
        });
        $('#wrap').mouseleave( function(){
            $('#nav_menu').slideUp();
        });
        $('#nav_menu li img')
        .mouseover(function () {
            this.src = this.src.replace('/ori_', '/hover_');
        })
        .mouseout(function () {
            this.src = this.src.replace('/hover_', '/ori_');
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

**DEMO.CSS**:

```
#clickable_div {
    width: 166px; 
    background-color: #9c9c9c;
    display: block;
}
#nav_menu {
    width: 166px; 
    height: auto; 
    background-color: #CCC; 
    display: none
}
//*{padding:0;margin:0} This will achieve what I want but eventually all my other elements on the same page will have no padding and margin
#wrap { 
    width: 166px;
}
```

By copying the code, you will see the drop down menu has messed up. It can be fix by using `*{padding:0;margin:0}` but all the other elements on the same page will have no padding and margin which is definitely not the desired output. I've tried set padding and margin to 0 for each and every element such as `#wrap`, `#nav_menu` but none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the `ul` which by default takes some margin. You can reset it independently.

try add this

```
ul.dropDown{
    margin:0px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dc65n/)**

Plus the transition issue on your menu while hovered in and out quickily can be resolved using `stop()` and also note that pair event for `mouseleave` is `mouseenter` not `mouseover` So try

```
   $('#wrap').mouseenter( function(){
        $('#nav_menu').stop(true, true).slideDown();
    }).mouseleave( function(){
        $('#nav_menu').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
```

or just

```
     $('#wrap').on( 'mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
        $('#nav_menu').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLzWv/)**

Comment: Hi PSL, Please help take a look at my another problem @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019122/weird-behaviour-of-css-dropdown-menu Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you use the asterisk (*) as as selector in CSS, you are selecting every element on the page! That is a lot to select. Fortunately, CSS provides a way to select specific elements only.

for example, all you want to select is the `<ul>` on the page, right? Follow this pattern for a selector: `parent child{margin:0px;}` To make this what you want you can do this: `#nav_menu ul.dropDown{margin: 0px;}`.

That should fix your problem!